# Get child array information with Codeigniter Template Parser

Tags: php, codeigniter, parsing, codeigniter-3

I'm using the CodeIgniter3 Template Parser to avoid to have much PHP in my Views.

Now I'm in trouble because i usually pass a "big" Array to the Parser with some subArrays (that allows me to catalogate the informations) like this:

```
$vars['userdata'] = $CI->session->all_userdata();
$vars['gameslist'] = $CI->Game_model->getGamesList();
$vars['baseurl'] = $baseurl;

$content  = $this->parse('header', $vars);
$content .= $this->parse($template_name, $vars);
$content .= $this->parse('footer', $vars);
```

Now if I attempt to access userdata subArray in my header in this way:

```
{userdata}
   {username}
{/userdata}
```

I get this error:

```
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Effectively, the Parser with this format expects to get a list of similar items (and the userdata isn't, because is a subArray that contains the data of the logged in user).

Is there any method to get access to subArray datas? Something like `{userdata: username}` would be really useful.

EDIT:

Here's the Parse function

```
protected function _parse($template, $data, $return = FALSE)
    {
        // First check if we've got something to parse
        if ($template === '') {
            return FALSE;
        }

        // Retrieve and load all CI vars
        $data = array_merge($data, $this->CI->load->get_vars());

        // Check for loop statements
        $template = $this->_parse_loops($template, TRUE);

        // Variable replacement pre-processing
        $replace = array();
        foreach ($data as $key => $val) {
            $replace = array_merge(
                $replace,
                is_object($val) ? $this->_parse_object($key, $val, $template) :
                (is_array($val) ? $this->_parse_pair($key, $val, $template) :
                $this->_parse_single($key, (string) $val, $template))
            );
        }
        // Variable replacement processing (actually viable only for every variable defined in $data, not tags defined in the parsed template)
        foreach ($replace as $from => $to) {
            $template = str_ireplace($from, ( ! is_null($to) ? $to : '%EMPTY_VAR%'), $template);
        }

        // Datas fully replaced, we don't need it anymore
        unset($data);

        // Unparsed tags replacement (each one will be replaced by a Parser special tag - {EMPTY_VAR})
        $template = $this->_replace_unparsed($template);

        // Check for helpers calls
        $template = $this->_parse_helpers($template);

        // Check for conditional statements
        $template = $this->_parse_switch($template, TRUE);
        $template = $this->_parse_conditionals($template, TRUE);

        if ($return === FALSE) {
            $this->CI->output->append_output($template);
        }

        // And last, unparsed tags removal
        $template = $this->_remove_unparsed($template);

        return $template;
    }
```

And this is what $vars['userdata'] gives me:

```
Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1515464554 [id] => 2 [username] => Scimiazzurro [email] => test@test.it [rank] => 1 )
```

Comment: You've got something else going on. In my testing, If you don't supply the correct data to the template, it just displays the tags. You will need to show us your $this->parse as this is some wrapper method for $this->parse->parser('template_name', $data, TRUE ); And also what is the output of of $vars['userdata']?